# Is it possible to use features or some other technique to compare two sites?

Tags: features

I have a virgin copy of Open Outreach running alongside a copy where I've made configuration changes such as site name and configurations of various modules. Is it possible to use Features or some other technique to discover and document changes I've made?

Comment: Not an answer, but a hint: https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration - maybe you can play with this and tell if it helps? With code, I could answer, but with config? Sorry.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 8, yes you can. But if you are using Drupal 7 I doubt you can yet do it. There is a backport of [Configuration Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration) to Drupal 7, which might make it possible.

The reason I said you can't do it in Drupal 7 is that the settings are saved in database and it is very difficult to make a comparison of the databases for settings. So if you have already made the changes and don't have a log, I would suggest exporting individual features using [Features Suit of Modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/features).

You can checkout my presentation http://www.slideshare.net/gokulnk/features-15841090 for related Features modules which will make your work easier.

As a suggestion next time you want to keep a journal of your configuration changes please use [Journal Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/journal) which should serve you well to keep track and document your changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the references. Journal in particular looks like what I've been looking for. There is so much to absorb as a Drupal newbie! I've had many years of IT experience and formal training, but the task of teaching myself how to best use Drupal has been daunting.

Comment: I ran WinMerge against the two sites and discovered that, apparently, all data & module configuration changes are stored in the database (somewhere?) EXCEPT images & css which are stored as files at sites\default\files and sites\all\images. Is this because MySQL does not support image files? I installed Journal. It's quite nice. Checking into Configuration Manager is on my list of things to do. I watched some videos on Features this morning. I am very confused about Features. Maybe I chose the wrong videos?